# call rest Api from Spring boot server the best one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, api

i want to call external rest Api's from spring boot java project .

what is the best way to call , in performane and architecture point of view ?

1) Rest Template
2) WebClient
3)Retrofit library
or anything others.
 can some help me tochoose the best one for implementation.

Comment: RestTemplate is in maintenance mode (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). The new one is WebClient(https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient). I am not a fan of using 3rd party libraries if spring brings its own. Comparison of RestTemplate vs. WebClient https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-resttemplate

Comment: thank you @Devilluminati for the response. will be using the Web client.